# What is the best way to change a deep field in React's setState function?

Tags: reactjs

Say a component's state is as follows:

```
{
  a: { b: {c: 1, d: 1 }}
}
```

I want to change `a.b.c`. I heard that in React we should immutable object to change state. So may be i should clone the object of `state.a`, change the `c` field and pass it to `setState`:

```
const newA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.a)); // could use other clone method, just for example
newA.b.c = 5 // change
this.setState({ a: newA })
```

So what is the best way to do this? I am new to React. In Vue, we just change it and every thing happens. I don't know React's principle.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct and I usually do this....

```
const newA =  {...this.state.a};
newA.b.c = 5;
this.setState({a:newA});
```

Comment: But we need a deep clone, not a shadow on buy `{ ...obj }`。But a deep clone is heavy, so are there other method to do it?